# Get Facebook page posts to Wordpress with JS SDK or PHP SDK

Tags: json, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I want to get the posts from a Facebook page and show them on a Wordpress site.

Firstly, I tried with the JavaScript SDK and succeeded, but couldn't figure out how to call the access token from server-side.

Secondly, I've been trying with the PHP SDK, but can not get it to work no matter what I try.

I've been over the documentation so many times I've lost count. It just doesn't make sense to me.

This is the PHP where I'm currently at:

```
require_once( 'out-fb/src/Facebook/autoload.php' );

$app_id = "{app-id}";
$secret = "{app-secret}";
$access_token = "{access-token}";

$fb = new Facebook([
  'app_id' => $app_id,
  'app_secret' => $secret,
  'default_graph_version' => 'v5.0',
  'default_access_token' => $access_token
  ]);

try {
    // $response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
    $response = $fb->get('/{page-id}}/posts?fields=message,full_picture,created_time&limit=5');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
```

I don't exactly know how to translate the JSON and get the code to my front-end, but even now I get an error from WP saying "The site is experiencing technical difficulties."

If someone could guide me through the PHP SDK or maybe show me how to place the access_token server-side with the JS SDK, I'd be so damn grateful!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please show the error logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out.

I still don't know exactly how I did it, but you can see here what eventually worked for me.

I think what broke it was using `$fb = new Facebook([` instead of `$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([`

```
<?php

require_once 'out-fb/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

$app_id = "{app-id}";
$app_secret = "{app-secret}";
$access_token = "{access_token}";

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => $app_id,
  'app_secret' => $app_secret,
  'default_graph_version' => 'v5.0',
  ]);

$response = $fb->get('/{page-id}/posts?fields=message,full_picture,created_time&limit=5', $access_token);

$node = $response->getGraphEdge();

echo $node->getField('3')[message];
```