# Getting Facebook post content/data using Javascript SDK

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

To clarify, I just want some data related to the post and to parse out a thing or 2 from the actual post content. Even using the JavaScript SDK code for the [Embedded Posts social plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts) still ultimately just creates an `iframe` and does not give me access to the post's content or any meta data. i've tried scraping the post page using a cors-anywhere solution to no avail. Is there a way to accomplish this - using the Graph API, I'm guessing? In that case, how involved is the process? I'm not sure how much deeper my client will finance funding for this feature.

**EDIT**
I just came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58773025/get-facebook-page-posts-to-wordpress-with-js-sdk-or-php-sdk) that seems to use the PHP-SDK. Could this be all I need for what I feel could/should be a rather trivial task?